# how can we evaluate Char functions on SML?

Tags: sml

How can we evaluate Char functions in SML, like:

`succ #"A";`    should give me B, right?

But it gives me the error "unbound value identifier : succ"

Answer (score 3):

You have to load the `Char` library to use its functions. Either load it into the global scope:

```
open Char;
succ #"A";
```

Or call the function with the library name prepended:

```
Char.succ #"A";
```